# Subdomain SSL to Domain with Shopping Cart

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, subdomain, symlink

I have domain.com and secure.domain.com. Both are on different dedicated IPs, and I have an SSL for secure.domain.com

What I am trying to do is setup a shopping cart in such a way that login, checkout, etc all go through secure.domain.com, while just regular browsing takes place on domain.com

Is there a way I can link the files under domain.com to also be under secure.domain.com and if so:

1) would this be seen as duplicate content by SEs

2) is there some other disadvantage of doing this?

What I'm trying to work out is this: the cart is on domain.com. Nothing is on secure.domain.com, and sessions and cookies won't travel from one to the other.

And, unless I can link the two somehow, I would literally need an installation of the cart at both domain.com and secure.domain.com, and I'm pretty sure this is not how it's normally done for sites that use secure.domain.com

I'm guessing possibly a symlink or an htaccess config or both might be needed? But I know very little about this stuff so this is all new to me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you, do secure.domain.com and domain.com have identical content?

Comment: Are they both different applications? Or is it just one application with two bindings?

Answer (score 3):

Set your cookie domain to `.domain.com` and the session will go through all subdomains.

Comment: The question I suppose has a different aspect. Its about linking or not linking files of domain.com and secure.domain.com and duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Clicktrend and Echilon, set the cookie domain, and ensure that it is cookies from secure.domain.com are marked as 'secure' (meaning they will only be sent by the client over https)

Also, be sure to disable the TRACE method, as this could be used to steal session cookies. For further information about this, I find this to be useful http://deadliestwebattacks.com/category/cross-site-tracing/. Easiest way to disable the TRACE method:

> echo 'TraceEnable off' > /etc/httpd/conf.d/trace-method.conf

I would also recommend that you disable http (leaving only https) on secure.domain.com (it is generally sufficient to comment out the `Listen 80` directive in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

These configurations are correct for Apache httpd on RHEL 5 and RHEL 6 at least; other systems may need tweaking.